# How long can I stay in Italy after withdrawal from studies?

Tags: residency

Due to some problems I have faced with my degree course, I wish to withdraw from my studies and enrol again in another academic year. I would like to know the consequences so that I decide right. To enrol in a new academic year, it requires me to go back to my home country. However, I only have receipts for my appointment with police for a resident permit. Therefore, do I have to wait and receive my resident permit as I am working to get some little money? Or do I have to leave the country immediately?

I kindly need your urgent feedback on this. Thank you.